# How can I filter activities by record type?

Tags: soql, activities, tasks

**Issue**

How can I filter the ActivityHistories sub-query by record type?  When I use record type in the query it's saying the field isn't valid.

**Background**

I'm doing a custom last activity date for a hiearchy of accounts the excludes certain tasks and have run into a lot of issues handling the bulk cases since the task table doesn't support aggregate fields on `ActivityDate`.

In theory I'd do a query like this given a set of accountIds

```
select max(activityDate), accountId
from Task
where included__c = true
and accountId in :accountIds
group by accountId
```

While that approach fails I'm nearly there with this query

```
select 
  (select activityDate
   from ActivityHistories
   where isTask = true
   and included__c = true
   limit 1)
from Account
where id in :AccountIds
```

But now I need to filter on record types and it's given me errors.  Is there any way to filter on record type in the ActivityHistories query?

Answer (score 3):

You can workaround this by creating a text field to store the record type developer name and use a workflow to push a value into the field.  In theory a custom activity formula field, i.e. `RecordType.DeveloperName`, would work, but in practice the value is null when returned in an `ActivityHistory` sub-query.

**Formula Field**

```
RecordType.DeveloperName
```

**SOQL Query**

```
select 
  (select activityDate
   from ActivityHistories
   where isTask = true
   and included__c = true
   and recordTypeDeveloperName__c = 'ExcludedRecordType'
   limit 1)
from Account
where id in :AccountIds
```